# vba code to reference letter and number in excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

This is my piece of code:

```
For loopi = maxlastrow + 3 To lastrowrangetotal
issuerformula = Cells(loopi, 4).Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)
Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(loopi, 4).Formula = "=BDP(""&issuerformula.value&"",""ISSUER"")"
Next loopi
```

this part assign a variable to a cell expressed in "letter / number", let's say D35 in this case.

This piece of code manage to transform a cell expressed as cell(2,2) for example into B2 :

```
issuerformula = Cells(loopi, 4).Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)
```

I would like to use this variable to have in my cell the formula `"=BDP(B2,"ISSUER")"`

However, the way it is coded now returns that : `=BDP("&issuerformula.value&","ISSUER")`

I tried several combinations, removing ".value", doubling or tripling """,... no chance for me.

What would be the correct combination to do that in this formula `Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(loopi, 4).Formula = "=BDP(""&issuerformula.value&"",""ISSUER"")"`

Comment: I think `issuerformula` is a string? Therefore : `.Formula = "=BDP(" & issuerformula & ",""ISSUER"")"` - i.e. without the `.value`.

Comment: indeed, but with blanks between & and variable... I attached it in my previous code.

Answer (score 1):

it's ok I found the answer myself, it was a matter of blank

so, this works...

```
For loopi = maxlastrow + 3 To lastrowrangetotal
      issuerformula = Cells(loopi, 4).Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)
      Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(loopi, 4).Formula = "=BDP(" & issuerformula & ",""ISSUER"")"
Next loopi
```